# EJBContainer.createEJBContainer ConfigureApplicationException with Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I'm working with the build system Gradle and using TomEE. The TomEE examples are in Maven. By porting some test cases I observed that there a some differences which I can't fix.
My reserach code could be found [here](https://github.com/abstract-thinking/webservice-ws-with-resources-config)

I observed when having a beans.xml and an openejb-jar.xml in the [src/main/resources/META-INF folder](https://github.com/abstract-thinking/webservice-ws-with-resources-config/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF) with Maven the EJBContainer with createEJBContainer will be started.

But using Gradle leads to an OpenEjbContainer$ConfigureApplicationException exception.

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Cannot Load jar /home/markus/playground/webservice-ws-with-resources-config/build/resources/main.  The number of beans deployed (2) does not match the number of beans actually in the jar (1).  Please redeploy this jar.
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$ConfigureApplicationException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Cannot Load jar /home/markus/playground/webservice-ws-with-resources-config/build/resources/main.  The number of beans deployed (2) does not match the number of beans actually in the jar (1).  Please redeploy this jar.
    at app//org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createAppContext(OpenEjbContainer.java:428)
    at app//org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createEJBContainer(OpenEjbContainer.java:282)
```

When I'm deleting the beans.xml the EJBContainer starts without problems. Hard to believe that the build system is responsible.

Why does the EJBContainer finds two deployed with Gradle?
How can I fix this?
Is there some examples using EJBContainer with Gradle?

Thanks,
Markus